# docusign - webhook returns invalid XML?

Tags: docusignapi

This is what I wanted to do:

1. Using rest API send a document to be signed
2. Person signs it and webhook triggers XML containing signed document in this case PDF

What happens is in Connect log I see that API triggered webhook that is then picked up by requestb.in. In here what I see is XML is incomplete same as on my real Web service catcher procedure?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
  <EnvelopeStatus>
    <RecipientStatuses>
      <RecipientStatus>
        <Type>Signer</Type>
        <Email>lino@xx.xxx</Email>
        <UserName>Lino</UserName>
        <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
        <Sent>2017-01-10T04:42:34.857</Sent>
        <DeclineReason xsi:nil="true" />
        <Status>Sent</Status>
        <RecipientIPAddress />
        <CustomFields />
        <TabStatuses>
          <TabStatus>
            <TabType>SignHere</TabType>
            <Status>Active</Status>
            <XPosition>52</XPosition>
            <YPosition>104</YPosition>
            <TabLabel>Sign Here</TabLabel>
            <TabName>SignHere</TabName>
            <TabValue />
            <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
            <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
          </TabStatus>
        </TabStatuses>
        <AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus>
        <RecipientId>d6567258-6407-4bd8-a544-c12528e32XXX</RecipientId>
      </RecipientStatus>
    </RecipientStatuses>
    <TimeGenerated>2017-01-10T04:42:55.0381883</TimeGenerated>
    <EnvelopeID>e08dcbc1-a09a-459b-9b84-5b5Xb3f335XX</EnvelopeID>
    <Subject>Request a signature via email example</Subject>
    <UserName>Lino</UserName>
    <Email>lino@xx.xxx</Email>
    <Status>Sent</Status>
    <Created>2017-01-10T04:42:34.343</Created>
    <Sent>2017-01-10T04:42:34.903</Sent>
    <ACStatus>Original</ACStatus>
    <ACStatusDate>2017-01-10T04:42:34.343</ACStatusDate>
    <ACHolder>Lino</ACHolder>
    <ACHolderEmail>lino@xx.xxx</ACHolderEmail>
    <ACHolderLocation>DocuSign</ACHolderLocation>
    <SigningLocation>Online</SigningLocation>
    <SenderIPAddress>XX.XXX.XXX.XX  </SenderIPAddress>
    <EnvelopePDFHash />
    <CustomFields />
    <AutoNavigation>true</AutoNavigation>
    <EnvelopeIdStamping>true</EnvelopeIdStamping>
    <AuthoritativeCopy>false</AuthoritativeCopy>
    <DocumentStatuses>
      <DocumentStatus>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Name>contract.pdf</Name>
        <TemplateName />
        <Sequence>1</Sequence>
      </DocumentStatus>
    </DocumentStatuses>
  </EnvelopeStatus>
  <DocumentPDFs>
    <DocumentPDF>
      <Name>contract.pdf</Name>
      <PDFBytes>.........
```

But there are no closing tags or anything. This is all I get.

When I try downloading it as BLOB using base64 file it says pdf invalid or corrupted.

Comment: Is the webhook supposed to return all of the XML? Sometimes webhooks are just designed to notify you that something happened, and then you need to make a follow-up API call to get the information you need.

Comment: Hi Seth, According to https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/webhook-status seems like webhook should include it. Also from what I read on other posts PDFBytes should store the whole file and all tags should be closed too. I checked the file size and I am under 0.1 MB which should not be an issue then.

Comment: When docusign calls your webhooj, is it a POST request?

Comment: Yes it is. This is what I used as a bone for my code https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/webhook-status

Comment: I also tried using v2/accounts/:accountId/envelopes/:envelopeId/documents/:documentId but not sure how to parse the results.

Comment: Sorted this myself using getDocument API which returns blob.

Comment: Add that as an answer to your question instead of making it a comment.